# Ionic 2 Duplicate Categories pages to be condensed into one

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I currently have a recipe app whereby I have 12 different categories, I have 12 different HTML pages currently as they all have a different api call, but are the same in structure. An example of the API calls are

```
loadCategory1() {
  var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=///&_app_key=///";

  if (this.Category1) {
    // already loaded data
    return Promise.resolve(this.Category1);
  }

  // don't have the data yet
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
    // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
    // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
    this.http.get(url + "&allowedAllergy[]=396^Dairy-Free&allowedAllergy[]=393^Gluten-Free&maxResult=50&start=10")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
        // and save the data for later reference
        console.log(data);
        this.Category1 = data.matches;
        resolve(this.Category1);
      });
  });
}

loadCategory2() {
  var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=///&_app_key=///";

  if (this.Category2) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.Category2);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(url + "&maxTotalTimeInSeconds=1800&maxResult=50&start=10")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.Category2 = data.matches;
        resolve(this.Category2);
      });
  });
}

loadCategory3() {
  var url = "http://api.yummly.com/v1/api/recipes?_app_id=///&_app_key=///";

  if (this.Category3) {
    return Promise.resolve(this.Category3);
  }

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.http.get(url + "&allowedCourse[]=course^course-Desserts&maxResult=50&start=10")
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.Category3 = data.matches;
        resolve(this.Category3);
      });
  });
}
```

html is

```
<ion-content class="home">
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item [navPush] = "category1Page">
      <img src="assets/images/cat1.jpg">
      <h1>Gluten Free</h1>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item [navPush] = "category2Page">
      <img src="assets/images/cat2.jpg">
      <h1>Under 30 Minutes</h1>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item [navPush] = "category3Page">
      <img src="assets/images/cat3.jpg">
      <h1>Yummmy Deserts</h1>
    </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
 </ion-content>
```

Then in each .ts file for the categories they call in the appropriate function. Is there a way that I can just combine all of these and only have a single file that would dynamically change on click?

So if you click box 1 it will do xyz but if you click box 2 it will only do xy?

Comment: so you have 12 different API calls? and what is your expected format?? **why are you using Promise**?

Comment: Correct, you have the url which is the variable and then `&maxTotalTimeInSeconds=1800&maxResult=50&start=10` for example would be the dynamic part (end of the url to filter). They make it easier to call the API

Comment: can u reach me out in fb @ aravind2109 as I need more information on your expectation